# TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Please help me this problem, I'm doing on vue js v2 and i also new beginner but  I have some issue with cannot read commit. When I login and redirect to my dashbaord by protect route

Can anyone help me?

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        authenticated: false
    },
    mutations: {
        setAuthentication(state, status){
            state.authenticated = status
        }
    },
})

export default store
```

method

```
methods: {
       login(){
           axios.post('/api/v1/login', this.form)
           .then(response =>{
            //    this.$router.push('dashboard')
                  this.$store.commit('setAuthentication', true);
                  this.$router.replace({name: 'dashboard'})
           })

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$store.commit('{fileName}/{mutatorName}', value);
```

in your case

```
$store.commit('store/setAuthentication', true);
```

Comment: But got the still doesn't work too @Нигилист Джордан

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    Vue.use(Vuex)
    
    export default new Vuex.Store({
        state : { 
            authenticated: false, 
        }, 
        mutations: {
            setAuthentication(state, data) {
                state.authenticated= data;
              },
        }, 
    })


this.$store.commit('setAuthentication',true);
```